# How to solve a NoClassFoundDefError

Tags: android

I'm having a com.android.phone has stopped repeatedly at boot, what's wrong?

```
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.phone, PID: 5088
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime: Theme: themes:{}
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codeaurora.ims.ImsService$2
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.codeaurora.ims.ImsService.<init>(ImsService.java:301)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2887)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-14 21:57:12.530  5088  5088 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-14 21:57:12.542  1309  4614 W ActivityManager: Process com.android.phone has crashed too many times: killing!
```

Answer (score 0):

You shold  implement Multidex. I sugest you have more 64k methods. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html